# Is there a way to link contact "parentcustomerid" to account when creating related entities in one operation in dynamics?

Tags: c#, .net-core, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dataverse

I'm using the [Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client/) library to get and create data into my dynamics 365 env using a .Net core app. I'm trying to create an Account with a Contact in the same request using [this method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/data-platform/org-service/entity-operations-create#create-related-entities-in-one-operation).

It works great, but I can't manage a way to link the contact "parentcustomerid" to the Account I just created while still doing only one request.

I found a workaround doing an update after the creation, but it goes against the fact that I only want to do one request (the execution time really needs to stay as low as possible). There is the workaround code:

```
            var account = new Entity(this._options.Account.Name);
            account[this._options.Account.Columns.AccountName] = accountName;

            var contact = new Entity(this._options.Contact.Name);
            contact[this._options.Contact.Columns.FirstName] = dataverseContact.FirstName;
            contact[this._options.Contact.Columns.LastName] = dataverseContact.LastName;
            contact[this._options.Contact.Columns.Email] = dataverseContact.Email;
            var contactCollection = new EntityCollection();
            contactCollection.Entities.Add(contact);
            account.RelatedEntities[new Relationship("project_account_contact_AccountId")] = contactCollection;

            var accountId = this._serviceClient.Create(account);

            var contactId = GetContactIdByEmail(dataverseContact.Email).Result;
            
            var updatedContact = new Entity(this._options.Contact.Name);
            updatedContact.Id = contactId;
            updatedContact[this._options.Contact.Columns.CompanyName] = new EntityReference(this._options.Account.Name, accountId);
            this._serviceClient.UpdateAsync(updatedContact);
```

However, I would like something like this (which doesn't work since I don't have the accountId before it is created...):

```
            var account = new Entity(this._options.Account.Name);
            account[this._options.Account.Columns.AccountName] = accountName;

            var contact = new Entity(this._options.Contact.Name);
            contact[this._options.Contact.Columns.FirstName] = dataverseContact.FirstName;
            contact[this._options.Contact.Columns.LastName] = dataverseContact.LastName;
            contact[this._options.Contact.Columns.Email] = dataverseContact.Email;

            // New line that is not working because I don't have the accountId
            contact["parentcustomerid"] = new EntityReference(this._options.Account.Name, accountId);

            var contactCollection = new EntityCollection();
            contactCollection.Entities.Add(contact);
            account.RelatedEntities[new Relationship("project_account_contact_AccountId")] = contactCollection;

            var accountId = this._serviceClient.Create(account);
```

I was wondering if there is a solution to this or I'm stuck with doing a Get and then an Update every time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to generate some Guid's yourself, but if you do that, it's possible.

See the sample from Microsoft: https://github.com/microsoft/PowerApps-Samples/blob/1adb4891a312555a2c36cfe7b99c0a225a934a0d/cds/orgsvc/C%23/CreateUpdateRecordsWithRelatedRecords/CreateUpdateRecordsWithRelatedRecords/SampleProgram.cs

Answer (score 0):

If create an new instance of `entity` it has no id because it was not created in the dynamics until you run. The instance of Entity is located only in your memory.

```
Guid accountId = this._serviceClient.Create(account)
```

To link the account with the contact you need the guid of the account.
So before you linkt the entities you have to call

```
Guid accountId = this._serviceClient.Create(account)
```

Comment: That I know. But you still can create multiple entities at once like I explained above. My question is how can I link the "parentcustomerid" with the account when I'm creating the entities. The contact is linked to the account with the "account_contact_AccountId" but I also need to set "parentcustomerid" at the same time. How can I do that? This is my question.

Comment: Try ```contact.Attributes.Add("parentcustomerid", new EntityReference(this._options.Account.Name, accountId));```

Comment: Yes, this would work, but I don't have the accountId since I want to create everything in a single request, hence my question.

Comment: As I described above, this does not work, because you get the ID of the company only after it has been created in Dynamics.

Comment: Ok perfect. I thought that there would be a way since we can created the contact at the same time than the account using a relationship and relatedEntities. Thank you for confirming there is no way to link an additional field to account when using only one operation for all the creations. I will continue to update to parentcustomerId once everything is created each time.